# What is the purpose of ">" in "shell: >" within an Ansible task?

Tags: ansible, yaml

What function does the ">" character serve, in a simple Ansible task that executes a shell command? For the life of me I can't find documentation or mention of this! Here is the template for the task:

```
- name: <task_name>
  shell: >
    <command>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The `>` is a mark for yaml.  It means that the following lines will be compressed into a single string with leading indentation compressed to a single space.  There are some technical details regarding leading indentation that will modify how the final string is generated, but to the yaml parser the following are equivalent:

```
- name: task_name
  shell: >
    this is some
    arbitrary string which may
    be a shell command

- name: task2_name
  shell: this is some arbitrary string which may be a shell command
```

Comment: The relevant section of the spec: https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2779048

Comment: Ahhh so it's about yaml. Thank you!